# How to set content-Type on WCF request

Tags: soap, http-headers

My issue is that a testing app like Google Postman ([awesome tool, found here](http://www.getpostman.com/)) can send the message.
When I send the message it's always refused (the exact same message) because nonse is 'expired'.

So there must be something different about how I'm sending it...

There is... Content-Type is different, for one... but not sure if that's why...

I've seen some hints about accessing endpoint behaviours like:

```
 var whb = client.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find<WebHttpBehavior>();
```

But that only allows me to choose between xml and json.

```
whb.AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled = false;
whb.DefaultOutgoingRequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml;
```

I have a wsdl:

```
http://caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.wsdl
```

I need to call the WCF service's RealTimeTransaciton with headers that that are:

```
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;
```

Currently, by default I suppose, the call includes headers;

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

and Content-Type doesn't seem to be set.

So I tried to affect the headers of the request...

```
        var addressHeaders =      new    List<AddressHeader>     {
            AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("Content-Type", "", "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;"),
            AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("Cache-Control", "", "no-cache"),
            AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("Accept", "", "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;")
        };


        var client = new CORETransactionsClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri(url),addressHeaders.ToArray()));
```

But to my surprise, the result of this is that these 'headers' are added within the soap Envelope headers, and not the headers for the transport!

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <Content-Type>application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;</Content-Type>
        <Cache-Control>no-cache</Cache-Control>
        <Accept>application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;</Accept>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
```

etc.... lol

My web.config service model:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="CoreSoapBinding">
        <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="UTF8" />
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="https://my_vendor_url_for_service_that_is_Axis2_based" binding="customBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="CoreSoapBinding" contract="CoreRule.CORETransactions"
      name="CoreSoapPort"
      endpointConfiguration="">
    </endpoint>
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

How I call:

```
var msg = Create270X12Message(requestReferenceId, senderId, receiverId, requestDateStr, productionCall, prettyOutput);

var envelope = new COREEnvelopeRealTimeRequest
{
    CORERuleVersion = "2.2.0",
    Payload = string.Format("<![CDATA[{0}]]>", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg))),
    PayloadID = requestReferenceId.ToString(),
    PayloadType = CoreRule2PayloadType_270_5010,
    ProcessingMode = CoreRule2ProcessingMode_270_5010,
    ReceiverID = receiverId,
    SenderID = senderId,
    TimeStamp = requestDateStr
 };

 var client = CreateRealTimeOnlineProxy(urlMissouiri, username, password, requestDateStr);

 var response = client.RealTimeTransaction(envelope);
```

How can I add my collection of headers to the request itself, instead of the SOAP Envelope headers?

Comment: It sounds like you're way off, playing with this stuff. Look for a simpler explanation. If this is a SOAP service and you used "Add Service Reference", then there's a good chance that WCF is getting the protocol interaction correct - including `Content-Type`. That's especially true if the service you're calling is a WCF service.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I was thinking that too, but I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out why messages from from my client, which is based on the WSDL, don't work and the same message in Postman DOES work! I thought it might be encoding... But it's like the server can't find the nonse and created date content from my messages. If I don't send the nonse at all, from my client, I get the same result. In Postman, it says I need a nonse. What can I research or investigate to know what's the difference between how Postman sends the message and how my client sends it?

Comment: You could diff the message XML, but you have to do some work. You'll need a tool that can pretty-print both messages the same way, then you'll have to change the namespace prefixes of the one to match the other. For instance if one uses `xs` as the prefix for the XML Schema namespace, then you may have to change the other from `xsd` to `xs` to match. Once the meaningless differences are manually fixed, you can compare them and see the difference. I suggest a good compare tool like Beyond Compare.

Comment: Also, Fiddler has an extension that allows you to compare two requests.

Comment: The messages themselves are identical so there will not be any namespace changes required.  It's just **how** the messages are being sent. I have fiddler - I'll try to use that compare feature

Comment: Whoa...ok - the nonce looks like it is truly expired...according to the message... How is the following scenario possible : The timestamp for the message (ie when the system thinks it's sending it) is 2014-12-19T15:14:04.750Z. That looks normal as the time should be in UTC. My nonce 'Created' timestamp is 2014-12-19T03:15:20.755Z which is UTC, but NOT military time... my timestamp format was yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ, so now I'll try yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ (!!) Ok - THAT was the issue...jeeeze - Thanks for all your help @JohnSaunders - you've been very patient